# How to choose multiple values for parameter in ssrs2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I already asked about 2008 ssrs drop down menu for databases .. and what I did is ... just created the parameter(@Database) and changed the connection string of DataSource like 
[="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog="+Parameters!Database.Value]

This is working fine when I select only one database at a time. But I am getting problem when I selected multiple databases. It gives me error. [The error has occurred during report processing]

Can some1 help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: **Please** don't use textspeak (such as "some1") when asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select from a parameter-specified database where the parameter has multiple values. This is because your query only includes a single select statement - you would need multiple selects unioned together, when trying to union the results from multiple databases.

I recommend that you uncheck the option to select multiple values from the database parameter.

If you absolutely *have* to be able to select from multiple databases specified by a singular parameter then you will need to rewrite your query like so:

```
select 'DB1' DBName, C1, C2, C3 from DB1.T1 inner join DB1.T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4
where 'DB1' in (@SelectedDatabase) UNION ALL
select 'DB2' DBName, C1, C2, C3 from DB2.T1 inner join DB2.T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4
where 'DB2' in (@SelectedDatabase) UNION ALL
```

...

You would need to hardcode the name of each database to be selected in each SELECT clause, and would need to have a select clause for each of the databases that could possibly be selected.

Comment: What would the connection string then. Same or different

Comment: If you are going to remove the option to select multiple values from the parameter, the connection string should remain the same as now. If you are going to keep the option to select multiple values in the parameter, set the connection properties so that the connected user can select from any of the selectable databases.

Comment: I have to use multiple values. I did exactly what you said. I modified the query. hard coded the databases.Now I am able to select multiple values but I am getting result only from one database if I select 2 databases. If I select 3 databases I get records from all three but not all the records.

Comment: Is there any problem with connection string.

Comment: The issue shouldn't be the connection string. Can you copy and paste your amended query into your question, together with the names of the databases?

Comment: Mark is it possible I can send the query through mail.

Comment: Not really - are there some security/confidentiality considerations that prevent you adding it unaltered to your question? (If so, it wouldn't be any more secure to e-mail it to someone you don't know on a tech support site.)

Comment: Atleast your method is working. Now results are mixup. Is there any way to get name above each database result. for example:

Comment: query is same as you describe above. Just column, table and database names are different.

Comment: By adding a column to hold the database name and hard-coding the name of the database in the select clause - I have modified my answer accordingly. I also noticed that I was using `"` when I should have been using `'` in the `where` clauses (which may have been causing your problems) - I have corrected this too.

Comment: I figured out that "" thing before and i put only single inverted commas there.other wise query won't run. let me edit my query and lets c the result.Thanks Mark. Hope this time everything should work fine.